# How to display kafka topic message using kafka connect to TSDB database in Prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, monitoring, apache-kafka-connect

I want to monitor kafka topic message in prometheus. I will be using kafka connect for the same, but I want to understand how to get the message content details in prometheus tsdb.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use PushGateway since Prometheus scrapes endpoints,  and has no Kafka consumer API. Similarly, Kafka Connect Sinks don't tend to populate any internal metrics server, other than their native JMX server. In other words, JMX Exporter won't let you "see Kafka messages".

There are HTTP Kafka Connect sinks that exist, and you should try using them to send data to PushGateway API.

---

However, this is a poor use-case for Prometheus.

InfluxDB, for example, can be populated by a Telegraf Kafka consumer (or Kafka Connect), or Elasticsearch by LogStash (or Kafka Connect).

Then Grafana can use Influx or Elasticseach as a datasource to view events... Or it can also use a regular RDBMS